# textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()) is removing justification in textview

Tags: java, android, xml, hyperlink

This is my XML code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/img_banner"
    android:justificationMode="inter_word"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_size"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_size"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_size"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

And, I'm using this code to allow clickable links in `textview`:

```
txtView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Without `setMovementMethod()`, the text is justified but the links aren't clickable. And, when I set `setMovementMethod()` the links are clickable but the justification is disabled.

Comment: same issue when using LinkMovementMethod.getInstance() , the text is no more justified

Comment: same issue. I guess its (another) bug in android

Comment: Any solution for this @Martin

Comment: @ram sorry man I have no solution on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> > The issue you're facing is related to the conflict between justification and the LinkMovementMethod. Unfortunately, the
> > LinkMovementMethod doesn't work well with text justification in
> > TextView.
>
> One workaround is to use Html.fromHtml to convert your text to HTML
> and then use Linkify to make the links clickable. However, keep in
> mind that Html.fromHtml has been deprecated in recent versions of
> Android, so you might want to use a library like HtmlCompat for
> compatibility.
>
> Here's an example:

```
    // Your original TextView
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.txt_content);

// Your text with HTML tags
String htmlText = "<html>Your justified text with <a href=\"http://example.com\">clickable link</a></html>";

// Convert HTML to Spanned
Spanned spannedText;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    spannedText = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(htmlText, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
} else {
    spannedText = Html.fromHtml(htmlText);
}

// Make links clickable
Linkify.addLinks(spannedText, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

// Set the text and movement method
textView.setText(spannedText);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

> ```
> This way, you can have clickable links while preserving text justification. However, keep in mind that HTML parsing might not be as
> ```
>
> feature-rich as native TextView rendering, so you may need to test and
> adjust your HTML content accordingly.